# Отображение старших разрядов нулями перед цифрой

Tags: c++

Как можно вывести число от `0` до `9` в таком виде `00, 01, 02`, то есть, чтобы ноль был перед цифрой?

Comment: `printf("%05d",value);` ?

Comment: @pavel только 05 - это до 5 символов нулями расширяет.

Comment: @pavel и к тому же это сишное решение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. По комментарию **@pavel**, конечно же, самый простой вариант, который приходит на ум:

   ```
   cout << 0 << value;
   ```

   Пример: [ideone](http://ideone.com/8Ejjcd)

---

2. Можно через Си-шную функцию `printf`:

   ```
   int dd = 1, mm = 9, yy = 1;
   printf("%02d - %02d - %04d", mm, dd, yy);
   ```

   Пример: [ideone](http://ideone.com/9edGm3)

---

3. Можно через `sprintf`:

   ```
   int dd = 1, mm = 9, yy = 1;
   char s[25];
   sprintf(s, "%02d - %02d - %04d", mm, dd, yy);
   cout << s;
   ```

   Пример: [ideone](http://ideone.com/HTt8dd)

---

4. Используя `<iomanip>`:

   ```
   cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << 5;
   ```

   Пример: [ideone](http://ideone.com/3P1CA2)

Comment: а можно просто `cout <<0<<value;`

Comment: @pavel о самом простом и логичном варианте почему-то не подумал)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::cout << std::setw(2);
        std::cout << std::setfill('0');    
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[std::setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/)
[std::setfill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/)